# Compare values when object not received (TypeScript, Aurelia)

Tags: typescript, compare, aurelia, router, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare defined `role` (in my  `app.ts`) and revived role from `WebServer`. But when I'm not logged I have problem with compare values:

This is what I'm doing:

```
export class RoutingAuthorizeStep {

 public readonly userIdentity: UserIdentityModel;

 constructor (userIdentity: UserIdentityModel) {
    this.userIdentity = userIdentity;}

  run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) : Promise<any> {

  let requiredRoles = navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions()
                    .map(i => i.config.settings.roles)[0] as string[];
                    //requiredRoles is example 'superUser'

  let isUserInRole = requiredRoles?
    requiredRoles.some(r => r === this.userIdentity.role) : true;
  }
 }
```

When I checked into debug:
`console.log(this.userIdentity.role);`

I have this message:

```
aurelia-logging-console.js?dc89:45 ERROR [app-router] TypeError: 
                                                  Cannot read property 'role' of undefined
at RoutingAuthorizeStep.run (routing-authorize-step.ts?008f:30)
at next (aurelia-router.js?e32b:433)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an Aurelia dev but this seems like a simple JS problem unless i'm wrong. assuming the error is in the "isUserInRole" you could do this.

```
  let isUserInRole = requiredRoles?
    requiredRoles.some(r => this.userIdentity && r === this.userIdentity.role) : true;
  }
```

Basically just check if your userIdentity exists before checking its role.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks I figure out how to resolve the issue (I did separe answer), But I dont know why still `some` its not working on my site....what kind of library may I miss?

Comment: Some should work on all common browsers it is native javascript. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Browser_compatibility 
My bet would be that your RequiredRoles array is empty. Try console Logging it. I think you may be using your map incorrectly but i dont know what your data structure looks like. If you want I could have a look at it if you can edit your answer and show the output of getAllInstructions in a consoleLog so that we can have a better idea of the underlying data.

Comment: can you ping me inside chat? that I can provide you more details ?

Comment: Hey, Sorry i cant seem to figure out how to start a chat maybe my rep is too low? I have no clue. If you start one with me i'll be more than happy to help!

Comment: I have found chat and created new one,  you have been added there, we can start then talk

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it in this why:

```
 run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) : Promise<any> {
  if (this.userIdentity == null)
  {
    //return to login
  }
  else
  {
     let requiredRoles: string;
     requiredRoles = navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions()
                                          .map(i => i.config.settings.roles)[0];    
      if (requiredRoles === this.userIdentity.role)
       {        
        return next();
       }
        //return to login
   }
}
```

It's working. But still `requiredRoles.some` is problem - maybe some `library is missing`.